# pROC: Lower Bound of Sensitivity is not displayed right on ROC-Curve

Tags: r, plot, proc, confidence-interval

I can't find the bug in my code:
At a threshold of *0.3173677* the following sensitivity + 95 % CI should be plotted:

*-->* *low: 0.70590    median: 0.8235  upper: 0.9412*

Unfortunately the lower bound of se is not plotted right. As you can see in the plot, it is something like 0.68 and should be more close to 0.71. I do not have this problem with my other plots. I have compared my other codes to the one you can see in this post, but I am not able to find the error.

Hope you can help me out.

```
  y_pred_gesund = c(0.00578237, 0.05329814, 0.06638863, 0.11657998, 0.09474952,
       0.04716528, 0.25119904, 0.47698594, 0.35833103, 0.15637362,
       0.27704507, 0.65919458, 0.24238073, 0.14910174, 0.69475357,
       0.50563552, 0.80002238, 0.7051007 , 0.44420608, 0.21037749,
       0.06397617, 0.11677541, 0.22466454, 0.56244532, 0.67774251,
       0.29863889, 0.89408624, 0.17934509, 0.18724151, 0.79841682,
       0.26589102, 0.19238419, 0.21952037, 0.06087548, 0.126379  ,
       0.03503891, 0.04095548, 0.22670706, 0.14717827, 0.72644492,
       0.40010552, 0.13536545, 0.1537661 , 0.20038037, 0.23552361,
       0.08008775, 0.59824239, 0.39967286, 0.07968716, 0.08699301,
       0.35625533, 0.6098194 , 0.60030958, 0.50903341, 0.79489929,
       0.47671656, 0.7150811 , 0.5059392 , 0.11725486, 0.63610276,
       0.33609659, 0.48355634, 0.87606138, 0.92928469, 0.69375865,
       0.97552441, 0.76878145, 0.64389963, 0.85130681, 0.61455325,
       0.56401338, 0.26522224, 0.95388585, 0.63344538, 0.1296849 ,
       0.47407066, 0.8483158 , 0.90031392, 0.8269378 )

y_true_gesund = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)


set.seed(99)
boot = 2000

rocobj <- roc(y_true_gesund, y_pred_gesund)
print(ci.thresholds(rocobj,method = 'bootstrap',boot.n = boot))
print(ci.auc(rocobj, method = 'bootstrap', boot.n=boot))
ci.auc(rocobj, method = 'bootstrap', boot.n=boot)
###
ci.sp.obj <- ci.sp(rocobj, sensitivities=seq(0, 1, .01), boot.n=boot, boot.stratified = TRUE)
plot(rocobj, main = '',
     grid = TRUE,percent=TRUE, xlab = 'Spezifität',ylab = 'Sensitivität')
plot(ci.sp.obj, type="shape", col="lightgrey",density = 50)
ci1 <- ci.thresholds(rocobj,.95, thresholds = 0.3173677, boot.n=boot , boot.stratified = TRUE) 
plot(ci1)

OUT
      95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
     thresholds  sp.low sp.median sp.high  se.low se.median se.high
      0.0730379 0.06667    0.1778  0.2889 1.00000    1.0000  1.0000
      0.1170151 0.13330    0.2444  0.3778 0.82350    0.9118  1.0000
      0.1280320 0.13330    0.2667  0.4000 0.76470    0.8824  0.9706
      0.2582106 0.46670    0.6222  0.7556 0.73530    0.8529  0.9419
      0.3173677 0.55560    0.6889  0.8222 0.70590    0.8235  0.9412
      0.3790019 0.57780    0.7111  0.8444 0.61760    0.7647  0.9118
      0.4591384 0.62220    0.7556  0.8667 0.58820    0.7353  0.8824
      0.4802711 0.66670    0.7778  0.8889 0.50000    0.6765  0.8235
      0.5057874 0.66670    0.8000  0.9111 0.47060    0.6471  0.7941
      0.5632294 0.71110    0.8222  0.9333 0.41180    0.5882  0.7353
      0.6857506 0.75560    0.8667  0.9556 0.20590    0.3529  0.5000
      0.7100909 0.82220    0.9111  0.9778 0.17650    0.3235  0.4706
      0.7476132 0.84440    0.9333  1.0000 0.14710    0.2941  0.4412
      0.8134801 0.93330    0.9778  1.0000 0.11760    0.2353  0.3824
      0.8972001 1.00000    1.0000  1.0000 0.02941    0.1176  0.2353
    95% CI: 0.6418-0.8627 (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates)
    2.5%
    0.637892156862745
    50%
    0.761437908496732
    97.5%
    0.864722222222222
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the stochastic nature of the bootstrap *does* make a difference. You'll see this if you just run your `ci.threshold` function a few times over:

```r
for(i in 1:5) {print(ci.thresholds(rocobj, thresholds = 0.3173678)); cat("\n")}

#> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
#>   0.3173678 0.5556    0.6889  0.8222 0.7051    0.8235  0.9412
#> 
#> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
#>   0.3173678 0.5556    0.6889  0.8222 0.7059    0.8235  0.9412
#> 
#> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
#>   0.3173678 0.5556    0.6889  0.8222 0.6765    0.8235  0.9412
#> 
#> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
#>   0.3173678 0.5556    0.6889  0.8222 0.6765    0.8235  0.9412
#> 
#> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
#>   0.3173678 0.5556    0.6889  0.8222 0.6765    0.8235  0.9412
```

You'll notice that most of the time the `se.low` is 0.6765, but occasionally goes to 0.7051 or even 0.7059. This is something that you can see when bootstrapping relatively small discrete numbers: the results are "quantized" , such that they are *usually* all the same value, but are *sometimes* a different value.